# Pegar data atual no mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Colegas.

Tenho uma tabela do qual armazena as datas do cadastro com o DATETIME(), porém preciso verificar se a data do cadastro é igual a data atual, então fiz da forma abaixo, mas não funciona:

```
SELECT *,DATE_FORMAT(DataCadastro,'%Y-%m-%d') AS DataCadastros FROM cad_clientes WHERE DataCadastros = CURDATE();
```

Comment: Quando dizes que é armazenado com `DATETIME()` não tenho a certeza se a coluna na base de dados está em formato `DATETIME` ou `VARCHAR`. É `DATETIME` ou `VARCHAR`? Se não tenta usar `SELECT STR_TO_DATE(DataCadastro,'%Y-%m-%d') etc...`

Comment: já tentou fazer a comparação com o now()?

Comment: O formato do campo é Datetime.

Comment: Oi Alexandre. Sim. Também não funcionou...

Comment: chegou a dar uma olhada na documentação, pra ver se o retorno do now ou do curdate é igual a esse formato que vc ta usando? ('%Y-%m-%d')

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Soluções:

### 1. Mantendo a estrutura atual da tabela:

Formate a coluna **DataCadastro** dentro da cláusula `where` para comparar dois valores `DATE`:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM cad_clientes WHERE DATE_FORMAT(DataCadastro, '%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE();
+----+---------------------+
| id | DataCadastro        |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 2016-03-02 18:27:17 |
|  2 | 2016-03-02 00:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+
```

### 2. Alterando a estrutura da tabela:

**Atenção: só use essa solução se você tiver certeza que não precisa dos horários contidos nos registors no campo *DataCadastro*. Uma vez que você alterar o tipo do campo na tabela, os horários serão perdidos!**

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE cad_clientes MODIFY DataCadastro DATE;
```

todos os registros:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM cad_clientes;
+----+--------------+
| id | DataCadastro |
+----+--------------+
|  1 | 2016-03-02   |
|  2 | 2016-03-02   |
+----+--------------+
```

e apenas os registros com seu filtro:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM cad_clientes WHERE DataCadastro = CURDATE();
+----+--------------+
| id | DataCadastro |
+----+--------------+
|  1 | 2016-03-02   |
|  2 | 2016-03-02   |
+----+--------------+
```

## Explicação:

Seu problema é provavelmente porque seu campo **DataCadastro** é do tipo `DATETIME`, ou seja, **data + tempo**, e você tenta realizar uma comparação com o valor retornado pela função `CURDATE()`, a qual retorna apenas uma data no formato `'YYYY-MM-DD'`.

Sua pesquisa **daria** certo se seus registros tivessem sempre o valor de **DataCadastro** com o horário zerado, tipo `2016-03-02 00:00:00`, mas quando o valor da coluna tem algum horário definido, e.g. `2016-03-02 18:27:17`, a comparação com `CURDATE()` falha.

Veja só:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM cad_clientes;
+----+---------------------+
| id | DataCadastro        |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 2016-03-02 18:27:17 |
|  2 | 2016-03-02 00:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+
```

utilizando `CURDATE()`:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM cad_clientes WHERE DataCadastro = CURDATE();
+----+---------------------+
| id | DataCadastro        |
+----+---------------------+
|  2 | 2016-03-02 00:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+
```

## Observação:

Acho estranho que sua consulta sequer execute. Reconstrui sua tabela:

```
mysql> DESC cad_clientes;
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| DataCadastro | datetime            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Seu campo DATETIME se chama **DataCadastro**, e no entando em sua query você utiliza **DataCadastros**. Executando sua query:

```
mysql> SELECT *,DATE_FORMAT(DataCadastro,'%Y-%m-%d') AS DataCadastros FROM cad_clientes WHERE DataCadastros = CURDATE();
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'DataCadastros' in 'where clause'
```

Answer (score 1):

O tipo `datetime` possui o formato `Y-m-d H:i:s`, ou seja, a data e o horário.

Para fazer a comparação da data ignorando o horário, utilize a função `DATE()`

Exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM cad_clientes WHERE DATE(DataCadastro) = CURDATE();
```